# Jquery table not displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-ui

I am trying to use code that works in an onclick function of a button in an href click, but it is not displaying.

I am trying to hide the searchTable and display the new table, but can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

[My Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CLqdz/1/)

```
  $("#searchTable").hide();

var table = $('<table />').attr({
                  "id": "searchTableResult",
                  "width": "75%",
                  "border": "1",
                  "cellpadding": "0",
                  "cellspacing": "0"
                });

                thead = $('<thead />'),
                tbody = $('<tbody />'),
                tr = $('<tr />'),
                th = $('<th />'),
                td = $('<td />');
                a = $('<a />').attr({
                  "class": "set-url",
                  "href": "#"
                });
            thead.append( // append a new row to thead
                tr.clone()
                    .append(th.clone().text('Name')) // populate th with labels
                    .append(th.clone().text('Set'))
    );           


    });
```

Comment: It works when you click `Go`, the code above is supposed to run when you click on the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't forget to append the thead to the table and the table to the DOM

```
$('body').append(table.append(thead));
```

It looks like you've created a table var but never even use it.

Comment: The fiddle has `$('#search').empty().append(table.append(thead).append(tbody));`

Comment: But that's apparently in a different event handler than the one he's having trouble with.

Answer (score 1):

Did you insert the table inside the document?

```
$("body").append(table.append(thead));
```

The variable `table` has been never used. :)